# Is there a way to incorporate a laravel with a swiper slider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiper.js

I am new to laravel so this might be a dumb question but I am trying to reduce duplication in my code using partials as each page on my app has a swiper slideshow.

I first created a partial in slider.blade.php:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        @yield('slide-image')
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>

    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
</div>
```

I then incorporated the partial in the main.blade.php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

@include('partials._head')
<body>

@include('partials._pageloader')
@include('partials._navbar')

@include('partials._slider') <!---- Here  ---->
@yield('content')


@include('partials._scrolltotop')   

@include('partials._footer')

@include('partials._bottom')


</body>

</html>
```

To add the slide on the homepage, for example, have added the slider image section.

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', 'Dialhouse Hotel')
@section('slide-image', 'div class="swiper-slide" style="<img src="http://dialhousehotel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.jpg" alt="project-1" heigth="360px" width="360px">"></div>')
@section('content')



    @include('partials._contactform')

    @include('partials._googlemaps')

@endsection
```

However, The problem is the image does not appear on the page. It outputs `<div class="swiper-slide" style="<img src="http://dialhousehotel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.jpg" alt="project-1" heigth="360px" width="360px">"></div>` as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
@section('slide-image')

    <div class="swiper-slide" style="<img src="http://dialhousehotel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.jpg" alt="project-1" heigth="360px" width="360px">"></div>

@endsection
```

Comment: yeah, this works when you add background-image:url() instead of img src. Thank you so much.

Comment: If I add the `background-image:url()` to my answer, that is still answer your question ?

Comment: Nah I did it its fine

Answer (score 0):

```
@section('slide-image')
    <div class="swiper-slide" style="src="{{asset('http://dialhousehotel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.jpg')}}""></div>
<img >
@endsection
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.