# is there any proper way to integrate swiper in laravel?

Tags: laravel, swiper.js

I looking for solution which can describe integration of swiper in Laravel. I searched on internet but didn't find any proper way to integrate swiperjs carousel in Laravel.

I use npm install swiper but don't know how to call it?

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/get-started?

Comment: I also was looking for a solution to this and found a good example on stack overflow this may help anyone also looking for a good solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648648/is-there-a-way-to-incorporate-a-laravel-with-a-swiper-slider

Answer (score 0):

Use CDN script is best option than to install locally sipperJs vie npm

1. use CDN scripts of swipperJs
2. put CDN script in  tag in layout.blade or index.blade in view directory
3. keep JS in public/js
4. keep CSS in public/css
5. add swiperJS layout in index.blade

slider will run....

if not run then maybe if any js script comficting it.
ps: no need to use other solutions like

var Swiper = require('swiper');
import Swiper from 'swiper';